# Short words that change based on their proximity to other vowels

Tags: terminology

In English, "a" becomes "an" when it is followed by a word starting with a vowel sound. A similar thing occurs in Spanish with the word "y", which becomes "e" when preceding a word starting with an "i" sound.

I have searched online and have found educational resources about which situations these specific substitutions are made in. But I haven't been able to find any information about this phenomenon in a broader sense.

Is there a general term in linguistics for words like this, which are replaced by other words in contexts where the next word starts with a particular sound?

Comment: We use *an* before a vowel to avoid a hiatus. Are you asking about *Epenthesis*?

Comment: @JoyfulSadness Clearly not epenthesis, since Spanish _y_ > _e_ does not involve epenthesis. I expect lexical tone sandhi in Chinese (i.e., where 一 _yī_ ‘one/a’ becomes _yì_ before tones 1-3 and _yí_ before tone 4, and 不 _bù_ ‘not’ becomes _bú_ before tone 4) would count as the same category here. The overarching term would be **dissimilation**, though as a category, that’s much too broad, consisting primarily of cases that aren’t function words of this type. I don’t know if a term for this category specifically.

Comment: @JoyfulSadness Well, historically, it is rather the deletion of the /n/ before consonants than the emergence of an epenthetic /n/ before vowels.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica: I know that (didn't want to complicate things for the OP).

Comment: The general term is _allomorphy_. We say /ə/ and /ən/ are allomorphs of the same morpheme that are in complementary distribution. Similarly, /ðə/ and /ði/ are allomorphs of the same morpheme, both spelled _the,_ but pronounced differently. And then there are irregular suffixes, like the plurals in _oxen_ and _sheep_, which are allomorphs of the {-Z₁} noun plural suffix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term you are looking for is probably [**sandhi rules**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandhi)¹. Sandhi is not necessarily restricted to short words, it can in principle apply to any word.

Examples for languages with rich sandhi rules are Sanskrit and the surviving Celtic languages with their mutations.

EDIT: Another term that is relevant here ist [**clitic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic), and there is a process named [grammaticalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammaticalization) that turns full words into affixes via the intermediate step of clitics. This process is specific to short words, long words will be shortened before entering the cline of grammaticalisation.

¹ The link goes to the German wikipedia because their description is in a better state than the English one.